# XWalkView renders blurry

Tags: android, crosswalk-project

I am using the Crosswalk project to replace the slow default android WebView.
Everything works fine and it is super fast BUT it renders blurry(on both ARM and x86 version) and on both emulator and real device.

By the way, even GeckoView renders blurry the same way while webview renders great.

Could you help me please?!. Thank you.

Comment: I have the same problem. did you found an answer?

Comment: Yes I added <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="21" /> to the manifest file and now it works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I forgot to specify the min and max versions in the manifest file

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

I hope it will work for you guys

Answer (score 0):

in my xwalk-command-line file (located in assets folder), I used the following parameters:

```
xwalk --ignore-gpu-blacklist --force-device-scale-factor=1.0
```

No more blurry renders in my ThreeJs page.

My gradle dependency:

```
compile ('org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library_beta:22.52.561.1')
```

EDIT: setting this in the html head solves the problem in some devices:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=0.5">
```